# AWS RDS DbConnections monitoring - odd flat red line without much meaning

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

When I want to monitor DbConnections to my RDS cluster in AWS console, the whole chart is scaled oddly, as there's a flat red line at the top of the chart around value 35,000.

This line can't be hovered over (thus no idea what it is), and also it causes all meaningful values to be almost flat lines at the bottom of the chart.

Please see the image:

[image]

##### Questions:

1. What is the meaning of that line?
2. How to get rid of it?